# Appending string from list to arrays after using NLTK postag

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested-lists

I have these arrays

```
ADJ = [] #adjective
ADP = [] #adposition
ADV = [] #adverb 
CONJ = [] #conjunction
DET = [] #determiner 
NOUN = [] #noun
NUM = [] #number 
PRT = [] #participle
PRON = [] #pronoun
VERB = [] #verb
PUNCT = [] #punctuation
X = [] #other
```

Now I want to insert the words respectively to the arrays above. Meaning if Hi == NOUN then NOUN.append('Hi')

```py
[["Hi", "NOUN"], ["my", "PRON"], ["name", "NOUN"], ["is", "VERB"], ["Bob", "NOUN"],
 ["and", "CONJ"], ["I", "PRON"], ["live", "VERB"], ["in", "ADP"], ["Germany", "NOUN"]]
```

The code below is what I tried but it did not work for me

```
if(detect(paraInput) == 'en'):
        tokenizedPI = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
        try:
            for(i in tokenizedPI):
                word = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
                tagged = nltk.pos_tag(word, tagset="universal")
                if(tagged[0][1] == "ADJ"):
                    ADJ.append(tagged[0][0])   

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "ADP"):
                    ADP.append(tagged[0][0])  

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "ADV"):
                    ADV.append(tagged[0][0])

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "CONJ"):
                    CONJ.append(tagged[0][0])

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "DET"):
                    DET.append(tagged[0][0])

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "NOUN"):
                    NOUN.append(tagged[0][0])

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "NUM"):
                    NUM.append(tagged[0][0])   

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "PRT"):
                    PRT.append(tagged[0][0])

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "PRON"):
                    PRON.append(tagged[0][0])

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "VERB"):
                    VERB.append(tagged[0][0])

                elif(tagged[0][1] == "PUNCT"):
                    PUNT.append(tagged[0][0])

                else:
                    X.append(tagged[0][0]) 

                tagged = nltk.pos_tag(word)
                entity = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged)

            except Exception as e:
                print(str(s))
        else:
            print("The String inputted is not in English, please enter a string in English")
```

What should be corrected in order to fix it as the error I am getting is

> ```
> for(i in tokenWord):    
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: The error is a syntax type. I think you should first of all remove the parentheses after 'for', and see if and what error you get.

Comment: The parentheses were the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code should help.

```
import nltk
text = "A Sample Text for token test"
tokenizedPI = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenizedPI, tagset="universal")
print(tagged)
```

This will return a list as expected.

```
[('A', 'DET'), ('Sample', 'NOUN'), ('Text', 'NOUN'), ('for', 'ADP'), ('token', 'ADJ'), ('test', 'NOUN')]
```